# AWS ELB boto3 Pagination

Tags: python, boto3, aws-elb

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwlBU.jpg)I'm not able to describe all the ELB's although i used Pagination its only return ~34 while i have around 1400 Approx. can someone help me out?

```
import boto3
elb_client = boto3.client('elb', region_name = 'us-east-1')
paginator = elb_client.get_paginator('describe_load_balncers')
resp_iter = paginator.paginate()
for elbs in resp_iter:
   for elb in elbs['LoadBalancerDescriptions']:
      print(elb['LoadBalancerName'])
```

I have tried to run this code but only able to fetch 34 elbs, but i want to fetch all of the elbs.

Comment: Always copy/paste actual code. Typo: `describe_load_balncers` and missing close quote on `LoadBalancerDescriptions`. Does awscli (`aws elb describe-load-balancers`) return the complete list?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hey @jarmod, it does not return complete list.

Comment: hey @Community, here i'm trying fetch all the elb's that are not attached to any of the ec2 instances. currently i have provisioned around 1400 elbs in AWS account, so while running above mentioned script it's only able to fetch the data of 34 elb's.

Comment: If the awscli doesn't list 1400+ load balancers then, in all likelihood, you don't actually have 1400+ load balancers. Also, the default quota of ELBs per region is 20, so it seems extremely unlikely to me that you would have 1400+ ELBs in a single AWS account and single region. Are you sure you understand the distinction between an ELB, a registered instance, and a listener?

Comment: i just attach screenshot. showing 1400+ elbs

Comment: That's far more ELBs than you have EC2 instances. Are you sure you have that many ELBs? Could it be a bug in the count shown in the EC2 Dashboard? If you go into the Load Balancer console, does it show 50+ pages of ELBs?

Comment: yes, it does shows. that's why i try to find out which elbs are not attached to any of the ec2 instances.

Comment: Are you sure your region is correct?

Comment: yes, i have done some sanity checks before running the script.